# Is there a way to set Standard In to a file in Inttelij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Using `ProcessBuilder` I can redirect the standard input of my process to a text file.  When I run the process `System.in` is a stream of this file and `Scanner` will read its lines.

However, if I am running my main class directly through`Run` in Intellij can I also set `System.in` to point at the same text file as when it is run through the process builder?

Comment: You should post what code you've tried that isn't working in IntelliJ.

Comment: the code to redirect standard in via process builder works fine.  what i'm asking is how to point the project i am running directly at the same file.

Comment: Post the code that you're trying that isn't working and we'll show you how :)

Comment: there isn't any code.  it is a question about how to get Standard In to look at a file.  I stated that when using process builder to run the program it works.  But when running directly using the Run button I have no inkling on how to do this.  I can post the working code but this doesn't seem to be the point.

Comment: I theory, `System.in` is an `InputStream`, you should be able to open a `FileInputStream` and then use [`System.setIn`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setIn-java.io.InputStream-) to passing it the reference

Answer (score 1):

You could call [`System.setIn(InputStream)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setIn-java.io.InputStream-) which *reassigns the "standard" input stream*. Something like,

```
try {
    File file = new File("c:/log.txt");
    InputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(file);
    System.setIn(fileIn);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I theory, `System.in` is an `InputStream`, you should be able to open a `FileInputStream` and then use [`System.setIn`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setIn-java.io.InputStream-) to passing it the reference

I say, "in theory" because I'd be cautious about doing this, in fact one of the first things I would do, is get a reference to the original `System.in` `InputStream` and reset it when your done, just because I'm picky like that

Comment: I was looking for something more like setting the standard in at the process level sort of how process builder does.

Comment: @user5797668 Well, since you're likely running it from the OS, then you might need to investigate the ability to pipe a file through the processes stdin from the OS level itself

Comment: @user5797668 ie `java MyProgram < data.txt `

Comment: is there a way to achieve this inside the IDE itself

Comment: i know intellij allows you to set command line arguments in its run configuration dialog but doesn't appear to have <

Comment: `< data.txt` isn't a command line parameter, it's a feature of the OS. So if you're trying to make Intellij do this, you will probably find that it can't be done